# Disable Unity switch desktop notification overlay?

Tags: 12.04, unity

When I switch desktops in Unity, a small expo appears as overlay. I remember I set its visibility to 1.5 seconds, but now can't remember where those settings are.

How can I disable it since it's making my Firefox fullscreen flicker as long as its visible?

I can take a snapshot if you don't know what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open CompizConfig Settings Manager. If you do not have it installed, you can find it in the Software Center or type this into a terminal: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

In the `Desktop` section, click on `Desktop Wall` (or just search for the latter). Under the first tab (`Viewport Switch Preview`), uncheck the box for `Show Viewport Switcher Preview`. The overlay should no longer appear.